# How to set Default time of React Date time Picker to 11:59 PM from 12:00 AM in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem when I am selecting date from react Date Picker Calendar I am always getting date with the default time 12:00 AM I need to set it to 11:59 PM? When a user select any Date with out changing time in calendar open in React date picker i wants default time 11:59 PM, If a user change the time so it will change otherwise if user only change the date i wants the default time 11:59 PM in which is 12:00 AM now? Thanks in Advance
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymeq2.png)

My code is:

```
                                            <DatePicker
                                                selected={this.state.endDate ? this.state.endDate : null}
                                                onChange={this.setEndDate} className="form-control" onClickOutside={this.openEndDatePicker}
                                                open={this.state.endDatePickerIsOpen}
                                                name="start_date"
                                                timeInputLabel="Time:"
                                                dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa"
                                                showTimeInput
                                                setDefaultTime={this.setDefaultTime}

                                                showYearDropdown
                                                showMonthDropdown
                                            />
                                            <button hidden={this.state.endDatePickerIsOpen} class="btn btn-light ml-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select Date" onClick={this.openEndDatePicker}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendar} size='1x' className="fa" /></button>
```

[Click here to View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOUnt.png)

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Image Description link availabal now @NishargShah

Comment: You've got code which apparently represents a React component. There is nothing there indicating the use of C# or .NET or Bootstrap. Please [edit] your question to either remove the tags you're not asking about, or include the code using those technologies that you want to ask about.

Comment: please make a demo of the problem that shows your problem  clearly, you can use code sandbox to create a live app problem

Comment: Please share code as text, not as images of text.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your Response, Code is available now

Comment: which date picker module are you using ?

Comment: @AbishekKumar 'react-datepicker'

Comment: Please, remove all unneeded indentations.